# Is there any option to create 4-D charts in TFS Dashboard? If yes, then what is the procedure to create those charts in TFS Dashboard?

Tags: tfs

I am able to create 2D charts/widget in TFS dashboard but not 4D charts/widgets.Let me know if we can create 4D charts/widgets in TFS Dashboard. If there is a possibility then, What are the steps to create them?

I have tried 2D widget in dashboard.

Comment: 4D? What would that look like? You can always hook up to the PowerBI Analytics service.

Comment: What TFS version?

Comment: I am using TFS Version 16.131.27701.1

Comment: To create 2D chart in TFS below are the steps: Dashboard->Add widget->Add Test Plan chart->2D charts (Pie/Bar/Pivot etc.) can be created. Similarly, is there any option to create 4 dimentional pie charts also with grouping.

Comment: Analytics service + powerbi.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any option to create 4-D charts in TFS Dashboard?

Create 4-D charts in TFS Dashboard is not available for now.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

BTW, just like jessehouwing said, since TFS integrate with Power BI, you could create multiple dimensional charts with Power BI and Analytics services:

Check [this document](http://www.teamfoundation.co.za/2018/10/11/tfs-reporting-using-power-bi-and-rest-services/) for some more details.

Hope this helps.